# CSS perspective flip animation flicker in Safari despite backface-visibility:hidden

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a Safari issue (both desktop and iOS) with a simple CSS flip animation. I've checked all similar posts and answers but none solved my problem and I need another take on this.

In short, I'm making a vertical blind overlay flip effect to demonstrate car window tints. Simplified it looks like this:

```
<div class="blind"></div>
<div class="blind"></div>
<div class="blind"></div>
<div class="blind"></div>
<div class="blind"></div>
```

The CSS looks like this

```
.blind {
  position:relative;
  width:calc(100% / 5);
  height:500px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
}

.blind.flip-animation {
  animation:flip 1s ease;
}

.blind:nth-child(2) { animation-delay:50ms; }
.blind:nth-child(3) { animation-delay:100ms; }
.blind:nth-child(4) { animation-delay:150ms; }
.blind:nth-child(5) { animation-delay:200ms; }

@keyframes flip {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0);
    transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(360deg);
    transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

The `.flip-animation` class is triggered by an IntersectionObserver when the container is in view but that's unrelated.

Different approaches I've tried: Keyframes with only `to:transform:perspective(800px) rotate(1turn);`, I've "experimented" with z-index, adding a separate perspective:800px, with and without the -webkit- prefix, added `backface-visibility:hidden;` and `transform-style:preserve-3d;` inside the animation too (also with -webkit- prefix). All of the things I try doesn't make a difference in Chrome (it looks good no matter what) but it flickers and behaves incorrectly in Safari. It's like the blinds flip behind the opaque background (container) when "below/behind" the surface so to speak. ***Are there other approaches to this that I'm missing?***

See these images for comparison between Chrome and Safari:

[image: Chrome, animation looks and behaves as intended] Chrome

[image: Safari, animation flickers and doesn't look good] Safari

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is with the

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

It's not being supported in ios and in safari.

In your code just replace the code with

```
-webkit-perspective: 0;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
visibility: visible;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yea, I found that in another post too and tried it without any luck...

Comment: it looks weird, bacause somehow half of the div vanishes... Sadly i cant test, becaus i dont have safari

Comment: Exactly, it's like the container is like an opaque, yet penetrable wall. It flips but we only see what's in front of the background (container with the car)

Answer (score 0):

The `transform-style: preserve-3d` property sets the 3D treatment **of children**. You should set this property on the wrapper of the elements with the "blind" class.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style